# Internal error on MySQL from outside the container

Tags: mysql, docker

I built a MySQL server image and could run its container, I could also access it from another container just fine, for some days last week, all of this locally on my laptop running `Docker 17.05.0-ce` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. Then, yesterday I could not access MySQL from the outside. It started giving me the error: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"`

Here is the `Dockerfile` content:

```
$ cat mysql/Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libncurses-dev \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  && apt-get install -y cmake

COPY mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz /usr/bin/
WORKDIR /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz \
  && tar -xvf mysql-5.6.30.tar \
  && ln -s mysql-5.6.30 mysql

WORKDIR /usr/bin/mysql/
RUN mkdir install && mkdir install/data && mkdir install/var && mkdir install/etc && mkdir install/tmp

RUN cd /usr/bin/mysql/ \
  && cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin/mysql/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/bin/mysql/install/data \
  -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 \
  -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/bin/mysql/install/boost \
  -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && make clean

EXPOSE 3306

COPY startup.sh install/startup.sh

COPY my.cnf install/my.cnf

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "install/startup.sh"]
```

The `my.cnf` file content:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0 # Allow client binding from any IP address instead of just 127.0.0.1
port            = 3307
sql_mode        = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION # This is strict mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
socket          = /usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
user            = root
basedir         = /usr/bin/mysql/install
datadir         = /usr/bin/mysql/install/data
log-bin         = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.bin.log
log-error       = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.error.log
general-log-file     = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.log
slow-query-log-file  = /usr/bin/mysql/install/mysql.slow.queries.log
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
wait_timeout = 28800 # amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection
interactive_timeout = 28800 # same, but for interactive sessions
[client]
socket = /usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

The `startup.sh` file content:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

if [ ! -f /usr/bin/mysql/install/data/ibdata1 ]; then
  chmod 755 /usr/bin/mysql/install/scripts/mysql_install_db
  sleep 1 # Needed to avoid running the script when this mysql_install_db file has not yet been released by the permissions change
  /usr/bin/mysql/install/scripts/mysql_install_db \
    --no-defaults \
    --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp \
    --basedir=/usr/bin/mysql/install \
    --datadir=/usr/bin/mysql/install/data \
    --tmpdir=/usr/bin/mysql/install/tmp \
    --lc-messages-dir=/usr/bin/mysql/install/share

  /usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/usr/bin/mysql/install/my.cnf &
  sleep 10s
  echo "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | /usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql
  tail -f /etc/hosts
else
  /usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/usr/bin/mysql/install/my.cnf
fi
```

And I can run it with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 -v /home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data --name mysql stephaneeybert/mysql:5.6.30
```

I can see the port has an open state:

```
nmap -p 3307 localhost
```

I can enter its bash shell:

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

And, from within the container, I log in just fine:

```
/usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

But if I want to log in from the host:

```
cd programs/install/mariadb/; bin/mysql -h localhost -P 3307 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

it  gives me the message:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

container expose port 3306.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# ...
EXPOSE 3306
# ...
```

mysql is listening at port 3307 in container, it should be 3306 here.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
port            = 3307
```

Then docker forward container port 3306 to host 3307.

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306
```